# git installation error missing installation candidate

Tags: git, ubuntu

I tried installing `git` on Ubuntu 12.10 using the command `sudo apt-get install git`. But I am getting error message like this:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package git is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'git' has no installation candidate
```

What am I supposed to do further?

Comment: On a freshly installed Ubuntu 12.04 box, I can simply `apt-get install git` and it will install git with all its dependencies. (Have not tried 12.10, but 14.04 is the same, and I don't think was changed in the mean time.) So I assume that something is wrong with your setup:
 - Have you run apt-get update?
 - What does your /etc/apt/sources.list look like?

Comment: Ubuntu 12.10 is no longer supported so the software repositories are no longer supported either.

Comment: @Trengot: exactly, see my answer below.

Comment: Hey, I am facing the same issue on 16.10. I tried this way. But it didn't work. Any other solution?

Answer (score 16):

Try running below commands.

```
sudo rm -vf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
sudo apt-get update
```

Answer (score 11):

First run this command to update

```
sudo apt update
```

Then run this

```
sudo apt-get install git
```

Answer (score 4):

The git package should be installable. In principle if something like this occurs, you should verify the following.

- Make sure that the contents of your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file is sane. It should contain something like this:

  ```
  deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main restricted universe multiverse
  deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-updates main restricted universe multiverse
  deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security main restricted universe multiverse
  ```
- Make sure you have run `apt-get update` before trying to install git.

Note that the above sources.list is for precise (12.04). 12.10 is called quantal. But note that 12.10 is **not supported any more** (EOL was May 2014 - see [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases)). So the solution to your problem might be that the package sources for 12.10 don't exist any more on the server, so the message is in fact correct: on the server there simply is no candidate any more...

The solution would then be to upgrade to at least the next LTS version (14.04).

Comment: Hey, I am facing same issue on 16.10. I tried this way. But it didn't work. Any other solution?

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem as well. In Software and Updates, *Canonical-supported free and open-source software (main)* was unchecked and under the *Installable from CD-ROM/DVD* section, the box was checked causing apt to look for the package on a non-existent optical drive.

Comment: After searching far and wide this turned out to be the solution for me. Thanks for posting this!

Answer (score 0):

I found a nice tutorial about git on ubuntu 12 [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-git-on-ubuntu-12-04).

It mainly mentioned the dependencies prior to install:

```
sudo apt-get install libcurl4-gnutls-dev libexpat1-dev gettext libz-dev libssl-dev build-essential
```

and to use this for the git installation:
    sudo apt-get install git-core
    sudo apt-get update

and further more it says:
Once they are installed, you can download the latest version of Git from the google code page.

```
wget https://git-core.googlecode.com/files/git-1.8.1.2.tar.gz
```

After it downloads, untar the file and switch into that directory:

```
tar -zxf git-1.8.1.2.tar.gz
```

cd git-1.8.1.2

If you want to do a global install, install it once as yourself and once as root, using the sudo prefix:

```
make prefix=/usr/local all
sudo make prefix=/usr/local install
```

If you need to update Git in the future, you can use Git itself to do it.

```
git clone git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/git/git.git
```

Go and check the tutorial and leave her a comment ;-)

Comment: It should not be necessary to install git from sources. In a Ubuntu box I just installed (12.04), I can simply `apt-get install git` and it will pull in all required dependencies including git-core, etc.

Comment: I guess your right, but that is what OP did, and failed. So I put some google results in (for what reason ever :-) but I did. ) I give +1 on your comment for the /etc/apt/sources

Comment: thanks. turned that into an answer. the actual answer may be that 12.10 is EOL ... :)

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when unchecked all options in "System Settings / Software & Updates" while disabling auto-update.
Checking back all checkboxes in "Ubuntu Software" and "Other Software" fixed the problem.