# How to install Git in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: linux, git, ubuntu

I have installed Ubuntu 20.04 on Virtualbox. I tried to install Git. I have followed the instruction on the Git website.

When I try to install `sudo apt-get install git` I get an error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package git is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'git' has no installation candidate
``
```

Comment: Have you checked if Git is already installed?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [git installation error missing installation candidate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30932121/git-installation-error-missing-installation-candidate)

Answer (score 3):

First, try `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`.
If that doesn't work,
`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:git-core/ppa && sudo apt update`

Comment: i did them too. but it didn't work. i found the problem. "After this operation, 196 MB of additional disk space will be used." this problem raised during guest addition installation for full screen mode. accidently  i have unchecked all in software tab instead of CDROM. After enabling all in software tab. i can install now. Thank you for the help

Answer (score 0):

`git` has been part of Ubuntu's standard packages for a **long** time; if your instance can't find it you somehow managed to install it in such a way that it's online package repositories aren't visible to the machine, and that your only source will be the `cd/dvd` ... check your `/etc/apt/sources.list` to see what is enabled.

Comment: i found the problem. "After this operation, 196 MB of additional disk space will be used." this problem raised during guest addition installation for full screen mode. accidently  i have unchecked all in software tab instead of CDROM. After enabling all in software tab. i can install now. Thank you for the help

Answer (score 0):

Your sources.list isn't correctly set. Copy and past the following command to your terminal:

```
cat <<EOF |sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ focal partner
EOF
sudo apt update
sudo apt install git
```